# Drag and drop table information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a home page with table and a few 'favorite' folders. These folders are for holding 'favorite' rows of information. Users drag and drop specific rows of information from the home table to the folder table. Rather than dragging the entire row (because my rows are very wide, and it can be unclear which folder you are dropping this row into), I have an icon before each case number that will ideally hold the information for said row. In this case, it's an arrow. What I need to happen is when you drag this arrow and drop it in this folder, the information from the 'dragged row' will append to the according 'favorite' table. This icon should disappear on drop, along with the corresponding row from the home page. Double clicking the folder will 'open' this folder to view favorite rows, both old and newly dropped. [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YK5fg/)

```
$( ".drag" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

$( ".dropTarget" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var dropped = parseInt($(this).attr('title')) + 1;
        $( this )
            .attr('title',dropped+' entries'); 

        var delay =  $(this);
        delay.prop('disabled', true).addClass('ui-state-highlight')
        setTimeout(function() {
            delay.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        }, 2000)
    }
});

$( ".dropTarget" ).dblclick(function() {
    $( ".fav1table" ).fadeIn();
    $( ".main" ).hide();
    //$(this).removeClass('glyphicon-folder-close').addClass('glyphicon-folder-open');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to change the cursor type while hovering the arrow. This will help the user. What you need is to determine what lines allready have been added to favorite. A solution can be to create two CSS classes. `normal` and `favorite`. For each line that have already been "favorized", add class `favorite`. So you will have some arrows like `class="drag favorite"`. In the CSS just set "favorized" arrows as invisible or undisplayed.

On the `drop` event of the `.droppable()` method, add the class "favorite" to the dropped arrow. So it will be not visible anymore. You can re-use this class later in a selector, to select all favorite rows for instance...

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. So how can I go about appending the information to the favorite table?

Comment: In this scenario, your arrow must embed informations about the corresponding row. You can use either an `id`, or a `data` attribute. Once your arrow has been dropped, get its corresponding row in the main table. For instance `var rowId = ui.draggable.prop("id");` and then clone the row in the new table. `var cloned = $(".main").find("tr#"+rowId).clone(); $(".fav1table").append(cloned);`. Of course, this suppose both tables have the same pattern, same columns etc... Look at your fiddle updated. http://jsfiddle.net/YK5fg/1/

Comment: And to have the row disappear from the table it is taken/dragged away from?